# How can i access DLL file's function if i don't have dll file's document?

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface, jna

I want to access dll file's function in java code. But the problem is that i don't have documentation of DLL file. So through DLL export viewer i can get function name but i can't get function arguments and it's return type. So what is the best solution for that? Is there any solution or documentation is mandatory?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is not feasible, at least not easily (or legally)
See this answers to a similar question [Is there any native DLL export functions viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548637/is-there-any-native-dll-export-functions-viewer)