# Input string not updated with dllImport using in c#

Tags: c#, vb6, dllimport

**INTRO**

The original working code is in VB6... But, when I try to convert and use in c# it doesn't work

**PROBLEM**

The problem is on this line in c#

> Result = Iso14443Anticoll(HANDLE, 147, Uid, MultiTag, 0)

Variable `Uid` doesn't contain (update) any value unlike VB6 it does

**USING DLL IN VB6**

```
Declare Function OpenCommPort Lib "MR705API.dll" Alias "?OpenCommPort@@YGHPADPAPAX@Z" (ByVal PortName As String, ByRef hCom As Long) As Long
Declare Function CloseCommPort Lib "MR705API.dll" Alias "?CloseCommPort@@YGHPAX@Z" (ByVal hCom As Long) As Long
Declare Function SetLED Lib "MR705API.dll" Alias "?SetLED@@YGHPAXEE@Z" (ByVal hCom As Long, ByVal Led As Byte, ByVal Addr As Byte) As Long
Declare Function ActiveBuzzer Lib "MR705API.dll" Alias "?ActiveBuzzer@@YGHPAXEE@Z" (ByVal hCom As Long, ByVal DelayTime As Byte, ByVal Addr As Byte) As Long
Declare Function Iso14443Reqa Lib "MR705API.dll" Alias "?Iso14443Reqa@@YGHPAXEPAEE@Z" (ByVal hCom As Long, ByVal ReqAMode As Byte, ByVal ATQ As String, ByVal Addr As Byte) As Long
Declare Function Iso14443Anticoll Lib "MR705API.dll" Alias "?Iso14443Anticoll@@YGHPAXEPAE1E@Z" (ByVal hCom As Long, ByVal AnticollMode As Byte, ByVal Uid As String, ByVal MultiTag As String, ByVal Addr As Byte) As Long
```

**FUNCTION CALL IN VB6**

```
    Dim HANDLE As Long
    Dim Result As Long
    Dim ATQ As String * 10
    Dim Uid As String * 10
    Dim MultiTag As String * 10
    Dim ID As String
    Dim Temp As String

    Result = OpenCommPort(COMPORT, HANDLE)
    If Result = 0 Then
        Result = Iso14443Reqa(HANDLE, 82, ATQ, 0)
        If Result = 0 Then
            Result = SetLED(HANDLE, 1, 0)
            Result = Iso14443Anticoll(HANDLE, 147, Uid, MultiTag, 0)
            MsgBox Uid //there is value contained after input in Iso14443Anticoll()
            ...
            ...
    End Sub
```

**USING DLL IN C#**

```
[DllImport ("MR705API.dll",
EntryPoint="?OpenCommPort@@YGHPADPAPAX@Z")]
public static extern int OpenCommPort(string portName, ref int hCom); 

[DllImport ("MR705API.dll",
EntryPoint="?CloseCommPort@@YGHPAX@Z")]
public static extern int CloseCommPort(int hCom);

[DllImport ("MR705API.dll",
EntryPoint="?SetLED@@YGHPAXEE@Z")]
public static extern int SetLED(int hCom, Byte Led , Byte Addr);

[DllImport ("MR705API.dll",
EntryPoint="?ActiveBuzzer@@YGHPAXEE@Z")]
public static extern int ActiveBuzzer (int hcom, Byte DelayTime, Byte Addr);

[DllImport ("MR705API.dll",
EntryPoint="?Iso14443Reqa@@YGHPAXEPAEE@Z")]
public static extern int Iso14443Reqa (int hcom, Byte ReqAMode, Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.FixedLengthString ATQ, Byte Addr);

[DllImport ("MR705API.dll",
EntryPoint="?Iso14443Anticoll@@YGHPAXEPAE1E@Z"]
public static extern int Iso14443Anticoll (int hcom, Byte AnticollMode, Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.FixedLengthString Uid, Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.FixedLengthString MultiTag, Byte Addr);
```

**FUNCTION CALL IN C#**

```
    int HANDLE = 0;
    int Result = 0;
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.FixedLengthString Uid = new FixedLengthString(10);
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.FixedLengthString ATQ = new FixedLengthString(10);
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.FixedLengthString MultiTag = new FixedLengthString(10);
    string ID;
    string Temp;
    string IDNow;

    Result = OpenCommPort("COM9", ref HANDLE);              
    if (Result == 0) {
        Result = Iso14443Reqa(HANDLE, 82, ATQ, 0);
        if (Result == 0) {
            Result = SetLED(HANDLE, 1, 0);
            Result = Iso14443Anticoll(HANDLE, 147, Uid, MultiTag, 0);
            Debug.WriteLine("Uid :: " + Uid);
            //There is no any update value just contained length = 10
            ....
            ....
```

**ADDITIONAL**

I already search some information to convert from VB6 to C#
, These Problem was already resolved

1. long in vb6 equivalent int int c#
2. Entry Point need to be set to prevent `System.EntryPointNotFoundException`
3. wrong input signature for dll function may cause `System.AccessViolationException`

Comment: Why is it a `FixedLengthString` and not just `string`?

Comment: @DavidG actually, I don't know what is the cause of my problem now so I try to make my code nearly the old version from vb6 first that why I use it

Comment: But you are not calling a DLL written in VB6, so why is the parameter type using that?

Comment: @DavidG in c# There is no string fixed length declaration like vb6 as you can see in vb6 variable declaration. However, whether it's string or what I using now the problem remain the same

Comment: I know that, but the DLL import is not for a fixed length string right?

Comment: @DavidG I have no idea what is the actual parameter for dll since it's very old dll with no any document left

Comment: Only thing that I know it's not .net dll

Comment: You could perhaps use a tool to figure out the parameters then? Like this maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548637/is-there-any-native-dll-export-functions-viewer

Comment: @DavidG if you still here, I have extract dll function from dependencies walker. `int Iso14443Anticoll(void *,unsigned char,unsigned char *,unsigned char *,unsigned char)` do you have any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SPECIAL THANK TO..**

OKAY... First of all I want to thank @DavidG for guiding me

**TO ANSWER MY OWN QUESTION...**

The input string is not updated because of DllImport function signature are incorrect.

I have identified my DLL by using Dependencies Walker as mention in this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548637/is-there-any-native-dll-export-functions-viewer)

> The tool provides name and signature of each functions in the unmanageable .dll

[image]

So, I have change some function's signature.

**FOR EXAMPLE**

> Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.FixedLengthString **to** byte[]
>
> string **to** byte[]
>
> Byte **to** byte
>
> long **to** int

**HERE IS UPDATE ANSWER..**

```
        [DllImport ("MR705API.dll",
        EntryPoint="?OpenCommPort@@YGHPADPAPAX@Z")]
        public static extern int OpenCommPort(string portName, ref IntPtr hCom); 

        [DllImport ("MR705API.dll",
        EntryPoint="?CloseCommPort@@YGHPAX@Z")]
        public static extern int CloseCommPort(IntPtr hCom);

        [DllImport ("MR705API.dll",
        EntryPoint="?SetLED@@YGHPAXEE@Z")]
        public static extern int SetLED(IntPtr hCom, byte Led , byte Addr);

        [DllImport ("MR705API.dll",
        EntryPoint="?ActiveBuzzer@@YGHPAXEE@Z")]
        public static extern int ActiveBuzzer (IntPtr hcom, byte DelayTime, byte Addr);

        [DllImport ("MR705API.dll",
        EntryPoint="?Iso14443Reqa@@YGHPAXEPAEE@Z")]
        public static extern int Iso14443Reqa (IntPtr hcom, byte ReqAMode, byte[] ATQ, byte Addr);

        [DllImport ("MR705API.dll",
        EntryPoint="?Iso14443Anticoll@@YGHPAXEPAE1E@Z")]
        public static extern int Iso14443Anticoll (IntPtr hcom, byte AnticollMode,[InAttribute] byte[] Uid, byte[] MultiTag, byte Addr);
```