# make a .h file from a driver to be able to use the driver functions in c++

Tags: c++, windows, driver, daq-mx

I recently bought a data acquisition board ("NI 6341"), which has a CD with the driver, but doesn't provide any library (.h) to communicate with it. I think this is because they only want the board to be used by NI LAB VIEW, witch in theory recognizes it.

So, how can I get access to the driver functionality (make a library), so that I can use C++ to control the board?

Is it possible to access driver callbacks in Windows and make a library?

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Miguel! Does your driver comes with dlls?

Comment: Only one with the name updateMnager.dll

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548637/is-there-any-native-dll-export-functions-viewer you can use this link as a base. Using DLL viewer of any kind you can track which lower level functions DLL is calling. Some viewers (that you pay) can export lib files that contains functions and etc. But in general if you fiddle around with dynamic linking you should be able to eventually figure out what is what

Answer (score 1):

NI provides [C and C#](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/5409/en/#toc3), [Python](https://pypi.org/project/PyDAQmx/), and LabVIEW bindings for NI-DAQmx with the installer on the CD/DVD as well as [online](https://www.ni.com/en-us/support/downloads/drivers/download.ni-daqmx.html#311818). After you launch the installer, choose the language support you want, and install the software, you can find the NI-DAQmx header file here

> `<Program Files>\National Instruments\Shared\ExternalCompilerSupport\C\include\NIDAQmx.h`

and some example programs here

> `C:\Users\Public\Public Documents\National Instruments\NI-DAQ\Examples`

And the [C reference](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370471AM-01/) is also online.